# Showing list of what's in ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I have a problem getting my JComboBox's drop down list to show a list of hotels by hotel name.

My ArrayList contains hotelNo, hotelName, city.

In my GUI, ive written this

```
 Object[] hotelArr = { databaseconn.arrayListHere() };
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    // this just hide some unimportant warnings
    JComboBox hotelList = new JComboBox(hotelArr);
    hotelList.addActionListener(this);
    frame.add(hotelList, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

I can click the drop down list but it only shows "[]". Brackets I think they're called. 
I want it to show the list of hotelName which is also stored in the ArrayList hotelInfo I've put in a method called arrayListHere.

So how do I do it? Spent many hours on this issue. Couldn't find an answer or help anywhere. I also checked the docs but didn't get anything I could use.

Comment: can you do this line : System.out.println(databaseconn.arrayListHere()); right at the start, and tell us what the value is?

Comment: Yes.  I just did it and the result was "[]".

But in my other class (databaseconn), it prints this "[1, Sas Radisson, Copenhagen]
[1, Sas Radisson, Copenhagen, 2, Grosvenor Hotel, Copenhagen]
[1, Sas Radisson, Copenhagen, 2, Grosvenor Hotel, Copenhagen, 3, Hilton, London]
[1, Sas Radisson, Copenhagen, 2, Grosvenor Hotel, Copenhagen, 3, Hilton, London, 4, Ritz, Oslo]
[1, Sas Radisson, Copenhagen, 2, Grosvenor Hotel, Copenhagen, 3, Hilton, London, 4, Ritz, Oslo, 5, Best Western, null]
"

Comment: from the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) about the usage of combo boxes *If you put other objects in a combo box, the default renderer calls the **toString** method to provide a string to display*

Comment: Couldn' get any of it to work. I think I'm too stupid, lol. 

I edited my code a bit but it's a bit overwhelming now. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone possibly help me through teamviwer and point out my errors and such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your Object[] hotelArr is defined was incorrect. Also, it's not possible to simply cast a list to an array. Instead, you must convert the list to a data structure, the JComboBox can handle. There are several posibilities:

---

**1. (best in my opinion, because:**

- guarantees type safety, if you are handling classes other than Object
- return type of `arrayListHere()` can be the interface `Collection`, which makes it more common, than a returned `List`

---

```
Collection<E> list = databaseconn.arrayListHere();
Vector<E> vector = new Vector(list);
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(vector);
```

---

**2.** if you stay with List as return type of `arrayListHere()`

```
Object[] array = databaseconn.arrayListHere().toArray();
JComboBox box = new JComboBox(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

your problem is that you get a blank [] and treat is as an Array (well - hard to explain in words, i 'll use code to do so )..

```
//you *certainly* get an array here
Object[] list = databaseconn.arrayListHere();

//and as a result you get this code
Object[] hotelArr = new Object[]{ list } ;
```

when you get the message `[]` then certainlty that arry is empty, wich leads me to the assumption that `databaseconn.arrayListHere()` is an empty array

a workaround for you would be

```
Object[] hotelArr = (Object[]) databaseconn.arrayListHere();
```

but pleas check if that array before brining it to front!!

Answer (score 1):

You said that your `ArrayList have 3` type pf data i.e. `hotelNo, hotelName, city`.

& now you load it in `Object[] hotelArr` and then you are adding it to `JComboBox`.

So how application will understand that which among `hotelNo, hotelName, city` to take.

so make one another `String[]` that ll have `hotelName` only.

then try to load it in `JComboBox`, then it ll work. You can't directly add object to JCombobox when you are multiset data in Object Array.

If you are passing single set of data like hotemName then it ll work. see this :

```
List<String > ar = new ArrayList<>();
ar.add("hotel");
ar.add("hotel2");
ar.add("hotel3");

Object[] al = ar.toArray();

JComboBox j = new JComboBox(al);
System.out.println(j.getItemCount());
```

see [this running example](http://ideone.com/blEz8r).

Comment: I've read all of your comments and I have tried to do everything. I failed. I guess I don't understand how to do so. 

Can someone help me through teamviewer or something?